# Error: SQLite Wrapper assembly for the current platform was not found

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

The structure of my application

[image]

Content mainpage

```
using MyBD;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
namespace MyApp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            historyBD HBD = new historyBD("history");
        }
    }
}
```

Content MyBD

```
using SQLitePCL;
namespace MyBD
{
    public class historyBD
    {
        public SQLiteConnection con;
        private string mynull = "0";
        public historyBD(string dbname)
        {
            con = new SQLiteConnection(dbname);
        }
    }
}
```

when you press the button , the line "con = new SQLiteConnection(dbname);" 
gives an error message : "A SQLite Wrapper assembly for the current platform was not found. Ensure that the current project references both SQLitePCL and the following platform-specific assembly: SQLitePCL.Ext."

What am I doing wrong?